# More Largeness is Larger, More Smallness is Smaller, More "Medium-ness" is?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Another single word choice here; this one is along the lines of magnitude, e.g., good, better, best.

In this case, I'm describing more largeness as "larger," and more smallness as "smaller." The word I need is one that would describe more "medium-ness."

To put it into context, imagine I'm describing different strains of pineapples; specifically the sizes of different fruit parts. Batch-A has more fruit with larger-length tops, more fruit with medium-density pulp, and more fruit with smaller-diameter seeds, while Batch-B has either larger or smaller numbers of fruit corresponding to each of these measurements.

I know there might not be a good answer. But I tried this same approach to another word choice question, and I got plenty of unexpectedly good answers.

Comment: It’s just more *medium-sized* seeds (for example)

Comment: *More medium than* has been used. I am not sure if that is correct. ngram shows that it has been used.

Comment: The goldilocks answer: those on one side are larger, those on the other side are smaller, the ones in the middle are *just right*! :)

Comment: Mean, average, model and so on.

Comment: Well there is always “*smaller standard deviation*”

Comment: @Lawrence - I don't think *medium* necessarily connotes *just right* in this case. It simply means *in between smaller and larger.

Answer (score 1):

Your example asks for terms related to the distribution of properties such as pulp density. You can divide density into low, medium and high; but the property is density, not medium.  You have a greater percentage of fruit with a pulp density in the preferred range.

There is an entire technical vocabulary to describe population distributions. You are trying to compare a population distribution (of pulp density) with a test function of the desirable range of density (medium density). This is a multiplication operation called a convolution. If you want to talk about more mediumness, find a statistician who is good with convolution theory. It isn't something you can just pickup in a weekend.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

More categorized as having large tops isn't larger. More categorized as having small seeds isn't smaller.

Batch A has a greater **proportion** of long tops, medium pulp, and small seeds than batch B.

Answer (score 1):

First, "fruit with **larger**-length tops" can be rephrased as "fruit with **large**-length tops", or better yet, "fruit with **longer** tops". The comparative form *larger* isn't necessary in this case because your comparison is between 'normal' and 'large', not between 'large' and 'larger'. Likewise with the term *smaller*. Hence those in the middle can simply be called "fruit with **medium**-length tops".

Nevertheless, you raise an interesting question: *large* and *small* have [comparative forms](http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/adjectives/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives-article/144846.article). Why doesn't *medium*?

The positive form (e.g. large) and superlative form (e.g. largest) are absolutes - they describe just one thing. Comparative forms (e.g. larger) are different; they describe the relationship between two things.

In the phrase *X is larger than Y*, X is measured against Y and asserted to have more of something, in this case, size. When used with just a single noun, such as in your phrase "larger-length tops", the comparative *larger* is used as if it were an absolute, but there is an implicit standard of *normal-length tops* or *medium-length tops* against which the *larger-length tops* are asserted to have 'more' length. Likewise for *smaller*.

Strictly-speaking, given two *larger-length tops* A and B, all we can say is that they have more length than a top of standard length. There is no assertion that A and B are of the same length. For example, suppose a top of length 10cm was standard (I'm making this up). Then tops of length 20cm and 30cm would *both* be said to be 'larger' than standard.

When we come to *medium-length tops", there is no equivalent notion of degree. If two tops are *medium-length*, they are of the same size as all other *medium-length* tops. Since it is an absolute, strictly-speaking there is no sense in which one top is 'more medium' than another. As such, there is no practical use for a comparative form for the word *medium*. Conceptually though, the comparative 'form' would be *more medium*.

Answer (score 0):

Since mediumer isn't a word try a synonym for medium:

- median
- average
- standard

Batch-A has more fruit with larger-length tops, more fruit with medium-density pulp, and more fruit with smaller-diameter seeds, while Batch-B has an average numbers of fruit corresponding to each of these measurements.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider, ***[more] medial***

> *adj.* Pertaining to a mean or average; average
>
> [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Medial)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing sizes in your example, the adjective **middling** would work.

> (As defined by Google)
>
> [middling](https://www.google.com/search?q=middling&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) - moderate or average in size, amount, or rank.

Answer (score -1):

There is no qualifying measure of medium. It is or it is not medium.

Similar to the use of unique.

A thing is either unique or it is not.